# Compose Compiler and Kotlin version compatibility when you're library developer

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am developing a library that is connected by third-party clients. Jetpack Compose requires strict compliance of Kotlin and Compose versions, otherwise it will be like this:

```
 This version (1.0.5) of the Compose Compiler requires Kotlin version 1.5.31 but you appear to be using Kotlin version 1.6.21 which is not known to be compatible.  Please fix your configuration (or `suppressKotlinVersionCompatibilityCheck` but don't say I didn't warn you!).
```

What happens if a client who uses my library would set a higher version of Kotlin? Will an error happen at the library level?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to worry about. If the client sets a higher version of Kotlin, he probably also updates the compiler version (`kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion`) to keep the code compiling. In that case the newer version of Kotlin and Compose Compiler will be used and there will be no warnings regarding your library.